# code to retrieve the You Tube page information

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

i am working on a project which aims in improving the You Tube video categorization, this is based on a research paper. Initially i need to collect the You tube data sets which includes comments of the videos, tags, descriptions, likes for a video, title. There are ready made data sets available but i want to do it using the You Tube API's. Can anyone just tell me how to start with it with a sample code and also i am confused about the coding platform to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sample application:

http://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html

There are client libraries for Java, Javascript, .Net, PHP, Python, Objective-C ..

https://developers.google.com/youtube/code

Comment: is it good to go with available data sets or use You Tube API's to retrieve the data sets?

Comment: I think it's a good option to try first an available data set. If the available datasets don't work with my problem then I would get a custom data set on my own using the Youtube API